# while converting timestamp to date, its getting rounded to nearest date in teradata

Tags: date, teradata

I am trying to convert a `timestamp` to date but it's getting rounded to nearest date in `teradata`. Here are the details:

```
event_ts = 12/29/2014 23:25:13.000000-08:00

select cast(event_ts as date)=12/30/2014
```

How to make sure that the date remains same?

Answer (score 2):

It's not rounding the date, it's adjusting it to your time zone before extracting the date.

See the result when you submit

```
CAST(event_ts AS TIMESTAMP)
```

You need to add an option:

```
CAST(event_ts AS DATE AT SOURCE)
```

Comment: what is date at source!!

Comment: >>select cast('12/29/2014 23:25:13.000000-08:00' as date at source)<< 
didnt worked?

Comment: What's your TD release? AFAIR this syntax was added in TD13.10

Comment: Version/Release is 14.10.03.09 , I used >>select * from dbc.dbcinfo<<

Comment: Is event_ts a Timestamp or a VarChar? If it's VarChar you need to cast to a Timestamp first: `CAST(CAST(event_ts AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AS DATE AT SOURCE)`